# Firebase - Send Notifications (Android)

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've an android app and need to implement push notification on it, send and receive **simple** notifications.
My scenario; When userY submit form about userX will send userX notification that userY sent you message...

My Question: Do I need to create server side layer (C#, PHP or Node.js) to handle this part, so from android send data to C# and C# send to Firebase ? or there simple way to do it direct from Android application ?

Thank you.

Comment: this is for ROR, but try this https://github.com/ranjithnfn/PushNotification-ios-android

Comment: Thank you, but I can't include FCM apiKey inside my app for security.

Comment: you no need to create server-side layer to handle this part firebase. for more details, you can refer link https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

Comment: You should have a look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Comment: @Damodhar this will be using firebase notifications console GUI only and not through Android application.

Comment: Cloud Function solution is the best, because it's serverless

Comment: Hi, Have you found any solution? If yes can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a server to send the message itself. You can even send from the bash shell.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json " -H "Authorization: key=Your_AUTHKEY" -X POST -d '
{ "data" : { "mykey" : "myvalue"},"notification": {"title": "My test 1","body": "bla bla"}
,  "to" : "Your_looong_TOKEN"}'
```

A problem may arise when passing a token. There can be a useful durability value (write to the base).
Just send a post request with the appropriate headers.

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry i am new in Android development and i don't understand what is bash shell you mentioned, i need to send notification from android direct, could you please explain?

Comment: Linux shell command line. So just for example.
Just send a post request with the appropriate headers.
Find example , how to send request post for C#.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you should have  a look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), specifically, [Realtime Database Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

Let's say you're using Firebase Realtime Database. For your flow where "*userY sends a form to userX*", it could go like there'd be a `forms` node for a users, where you'll add `form`s from other users, [and every time a `form` is added](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#monitoring_changed_values), you send a notification with [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). Similar on how you'd [send when using Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages).

Comment: Thank you AL... all application database are in azure so ill not use the Fitebase database but ill try Cloud Function.  Thank you again